# jQuery menu set first child as active, toggle classes upon clicking

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Right now I have a menu made out of a UL and the contents of that menu generated through a Wordpress post loop. I found a jquery script that worked for toggling an active/static class on menu items when the user clicked on them.

Here's my menu:

```
<div class="castmenu">
<ul>
<?php if ($new_query->have_posts()) : while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="biobox" class="static"><span class="castthumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></span><span class="charactername"><?php the_title(); ?></span></a></li>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
</div> <!-- end castmenu div -->
```

Here's the script I have running now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
var sidenav = $('.castmenu');  
 sidenav.delegate('a.static','click',function(){
    sidenav.find('.active').toggleClass('active static');
    $(this).toggleClass('active static');
});
  });
</script>
```

Basically what's happening now is all of the menu's li tags are being set to have a class of static upon being generated and then the above script toggles the static class to active when someone clicks on one of the menu items. Which is the second part of what I'm looking to do.

For the first part, when the page loads I wanted to have the very first li in this menu to have the active class but for the life of me I can't get it selected and the class set in the above script. 
The active class (from this first item) would also need to be removed when someone clicks on another menu item.

Is there anything I can put in the script above to target that item on page load and still keep the toggling classes on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain jQuery's [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) after your delegation to select the first nav.

```
var sidenav = $('.castmenu');  
sidenav.delegate('a','click',function() {
        sidenav.find('.active').toggleClass('active static');
        $(this).toggleClass('active static');
    })
.find('a:first').addClass('active');
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLGnU/2/)

A side note: [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is preferred over $.delegate as jQuery 1.7.

Also, you could switch out your two calls to `toggleClass` by just calling `removeClass` on your .active items, and addClass on the clicked item.

Comment: Hi Nick. The above script works great but I'm getting a weird hiccup. For some reason I have to click at least two times on a menu item for the links to process and load anything. It's almost like the first click changes the class and then the second click activates the link.

Comment: Without looking at the functionality of the other plugin you are using, I can't be quite sure. I've removed the ``e.preventDefault`` from my snippet (sounds like the other plugin might be handling the event) and delegated events to ``a`` elements within sidenav (instead of just static elements).

Comment: Also I'm noticing when you do click on let's say the third menu item, the class gets removed from the first and then if I go back and click on the first menu item, the active class doesn't get put back on. And it remains on the last menu item I clicked. It works great in your fiddle though.